# Convergency of $1+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{36}-\frac{1}{49}-\frac{1}{64}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this series convergent $1+\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{9}-\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{1}{25}+\dfrac{1}{36}-\dfrac{1}{49}-\dfrac{1}{64}+\cdots\ ?$

Can we write this series as function of $n?$

Comment: This is  $$<\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac1{r^2}$$

Comment: If you join terms in pairs of the same sign, don't you get an alternating series? Oh, and it seems absolutely convergent too …

Comment: Can you write the sequence $\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, \ldots\}$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: $\sum(-1)^{\lfloor n-1\rfloor}/n^2$, I guess.

Comment: It's also not hard to find what value the series converges to. It converges absolutely to $S=C+\frac{\pi^2}{48}$, where $C$ is the Catalan constant.

Comment: Please include additional context with your question: where did you encounter the problem? Why is this *particular* series interesting? There are many alternating series - it can't be that asking whether each of them converges is suitable for a general math site.

Comment: $=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\frac1{(2k-1)^2}+\frac1{(2k)^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

The series is absolutely convergent, so we may rearrange it as we please.

The sum $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{36}-\frac{1}{64}+\cdots$ is just $\frac{1}{4}$ of the well-known series $1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}+\cdots$, which has sum $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.  This can be obtained quickly from Euler's famous result $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

The remaining sum $1-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}-\frac{1}{49}+\cdots$ is somewhat less well-known. This sum is usually called $C$ or $G$.  Please see [Catalan's constant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

Thus the sum of our series is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{48}+C$.

There is no known "nice" closed form for the sum of the first $n$ terms of our series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

You may refer to [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) and [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s),$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).